# Task Summary Name with PSI in Project Server 2016

Tags: sharepoint, csom, ms-project, psi, ms-project-server-2016

Does anyone know how to get the value of Task Summary Name field of Task with PSI? Im using the WCF version of it. It would be even better if I could access that field from ResourceAssignment item. But there is only one properte related to summary tasks - TASK_IS_SUMMARYColumn. But what I need, is the actual name of the summary task? Can I somehow create a custom field to task and roll it down to assignment to show the Summary Task name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At the task level there is the [TASK_PARENT_UID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvcproject.projectdataset.taskrow.task_parent_uid_di_pj14mref(v=office.15).aspx) property which "contains the unique ID of the parent summary task". Use that UID to find the parent task and its name.